# How to feed json object data into D3 charts(eg bubble chart, bar chart) in place of .JSON files?

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, bubble-chart

1. I have the json object in a js file(eg **MyFirstMashup.js**) and I
   have copied the script for bubble chart in the same js file. In all
   the examples avaliable on the web, they have used json files eg.
   flare.json, xyz.tsv etc. I cannot afford to have this file as I am
   getting the data dynamically in **MyFirstMashup.js** file. Instead I
   have attached the bubble chart code below my existing js codes. But
   unfortunately the bubble chart code isn't working specially in
   data.json() part. I think I don't have to use this because I already
   have the JSON object. If not then what needs to be edited in the
   bubble chart code. The **MyFirstMashup.js** with the bubble chart
   part and json object**(var jsonObj)** is---

   var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(matrix);
   var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);   //json object

   ```
   var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
         .sort(null)
         .size([diameter, diameter])
         .padding(1.5);

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
         .attr("width", diameter)
         .attr("height", diameter)
         .attr("class", "bubble");

   d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) { //hw to replace flare.json
       if (error) throw error;                   //with jsonObj(any json object)   

       var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
           .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
           .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
         .enter().append("g")
           .attr("class", "node")
           .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

       node.append("title")
           .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

       node.append("circle")
           .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
           .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

       node.append("text")
           .attr("dy", ".3em")
           .style("text-anchor", "middle")
           .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
     });

    // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
     function classes(root) {
       var classes = [];

       function recurse(name, node) {
         if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
         else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
       }

       recurse(null, root);
       return {children: classes};
     }

     d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Then, instead of using the d3.json function you can create a render function like this:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(matrix);
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr); //json object

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
      .sort(null)
      .size([diameter, diameter])
      .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter)
      .attr("height", diameter)
      .attr("class", "bubble");

render(jsonObj); // And simply call it like this.

function render(root) {  

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
        .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

    node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
  };

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
  function classes(root) {
    var classes = [];

    function recurse(name, node) {
      if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
      else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
    }

    recurse(null, root);
    return {children: classes};
  }



  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
```

or remove the render function and directly use jsonObj inside `.data(bubble.nodes(classes(jsonObj ))`

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(matrix);
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr); //json object

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
      .sort(null)
      .size([diameter, diameter])
      .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter)
      .attr("height", diameter)
      .attr("class", "bubble");  

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(bubble.nodes(classes(jsonObj))
        .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });


// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
  function classes(root) {
    var classes = [];

    function recurse(name, node) {
      if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
      else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
    }

    recurse(null, root);
    return {children: classes};
  }



  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
```

Example fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/mzz9B/47/

Comment: You mean to remove the entire render() and insert .data(bubble.nodes(classes(jsonObj )). If so where exactly should I insert it. Sorry for being lame but I am a total newbie.

Comment: @RonnieDas I've updated my answer for the second part